# Subversion : best way of moving changes from a branch to another

Tags: svn, branch

I have two branches : X and Y. I want to replace a Y's subdirectory (y1) by its equivalent from X (x1).

For the time being, I do the following : copy x1 to Y, remove y1, rename (move) x1 to y1 :

```
a) svn copy https://path/to/branches/X/x1 https://path/to/branches/Y/
b) svn delete https://path/to/branches/Y/y1
c) svn move https://path/to/branches/Y/x1 https://path/to/branches/Y/y1
```

I think it is quite ugly...

How could I do it in a smarter way ?

Comment: Wasn't switch and merge for that? :S 

I don't remember svn very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to replace the directory, you can do that with two operations:

```
svn delete https://path/to/branches/Y/y1
svn copy https://path/to/branches/X/x1 https://path/to/branches/Y/y1
```

If Y/y1 is really already an older copy of X/y1, you shouldn't replace it all the time, but instead merge all changes since the last merge into it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just two steps:

```
a) svn delete https://path/to/branches/Y/y1
b) svn copy https://path/to/branches/X/x1 https://path/to/branches/Y/y1
```

Answer (score 1):

check out branch Y to a fresh working copy, and put yourself there.

```
svn co https://path/to/branches/Y Y
cd Y
```

merge the changes necessary to trasform Y/y1 to X/x1 into Y/y1

```
svn merge https://path/to/branches/Y/y1 https://path/to/branches/X/x1 y1
```

commit this

```
svn commit -m "Y/y1 now has the same contents as X/x1"
```

If y1 has a different name from x1 (not clear form your description), do a rename:

```
svn mv y1 x1
svn commit -m "Y/y1 now named Y/x1"
```

But, you know if your workflow requires you to do subtree merges like this (or worse the sort of tree surgery advocated by other posters), you're probably Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to move branch:

```
svn mv url1 url2 -m "commit log msg"
```